# Why does saving of lists in TinyMCE add extra list-tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I have a problem with TinyMCE that I cannot figure out, its a problem with both type of lists, `ol` and `ul`.
Instead of using "wp_editor" I am using below code as I need to have the jquery stuff (multiple textareas in a jquery-ui tab).
The editor comes up correctly, no problem, it displays toolbar, I can edit and save, add lists etc.
When saving the data arrives correctly as I can see in the logs and its correct in the database.

```
2015-06-02 07:34:21 REQUEST: Array
(
    [questions] => Array
        (
            [6733] => before<br />
              <ol>
               <li>one</li>
               <li>two</li>
               <li>three</li>
              </ol>
            after<br /><br />
         )
)
```

This is what I use in the code (I have tried various options of root_block, br_newlines etc) nothing seems to make a difference.

```
echo "<textarea rows='3' name='".$input_name."' id='".$editor_id."' class='tinymce-enabled required'>".$content."</textarea>";
echo "<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 tinyMCE.init({
  plugins: 'textcolor code',
  mode: 'exact',
  theme: 'modern',
  menubar: false,
  statusbar: false,
  elements: '".$editor_id."',
  forced_root_block: '',
  force_br_newlines: true,
  force_p_newlines: false,
  apply_source_formatting: false,
  cleanup: false
 });
});
</script>";
```

However, when I reload I suddenly end up with this

```
one<br />
<ol><br />
<li>one</li><br />
<li>two</li><br />
<li>three</li><br />
</ol><br />
after<br />
```

which ends up upon the next save with a tripple list:

```
one<br /><br />
<ol>
<ol>
<li>one</li>
</ol>
</ol>
<br />
<ol>
<ol>
<li>two</li>
</ol>
</ol>
<br />
<ol>
<ol>
<li>three</li>
</ol>
</ol>
<br /><br /> after
```

What is going on????

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: For starters I did not know that such a tag exists, secondly if you change my subject line you should get rid of all the other tags in questions asked by other users - currently I can see at least 8 subject lines in "related" that all have tinymce in the subject line.
Also it may be a good idea that when adding a tag to the subject line one of those red hint box should tell you not to do this ...

Comment: *you should get rid of all the other tags in questions asked by other users* see my recent actions, I am on a hunting spree :) lastly, there is actually a strong voice for the propsed hint-box, but it eventually never got implemented... Anyway, I must confess: I should have adapted your title in a more meaningful way - I will catch up to that ...

Comment: By the way: Is this a specific behaviour of lists? Or are tags added for any injected HTML?

Comment: sorry. got busy doing coding - now off to dinner. 
Thanks for the title replacement - much appreciated.

Comment: I found where the <br/> are added for the first case - an nl2br adds them NOT considering the possibility of "<li>asd</li>" - upstream suppliers code (paid plugin) nothing much I can do, I did launch a ticket and they need to do something as it's wrong. 
However what bothers me that none of the flags I supplied to Tinymce  makes any difference whether I use cleanup true or false, source_formatting true or false, I cannot tell TinyMCE to "just put the content into the textarea as you get it, do not fiddle with it ever!" ARGHHH!

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the `<br />` between `<ol>....</ol>`

```
one<br />
<ol><br />
<li>one</li><br />
<li>two</li><br />
<li>three</li><br />
</ol><br />
after<br />
```